# Timer is not getting updated

Tags: ios, swift, time, sprite-kit

I basically running a timer in the didMove function of the GameScene class in SpriteKit. The function basically just makes the player shoot bullets at 0.5-second intervals. However, the problem I am getting is that once the player dies, and I use `removeFromParent()` on the player, the bullets are still firing, as if they are just appearing in empty space.
Here is my code:

```
var timer1 = Timer()

self.timer1 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true, block: { _ in self.bullet1.fireBullet1(player: self.player1, scene: self)})
```

And here is the `fireBullet1` function:

```
func fireBullet2(player: Player2, scene: SKScene) {
        let bulletNode = Bullet()
        bulletNode.texture = self.textureAtlas.textureNamed("bullet2")
        bulletNode.position = player.position
        bulletNode.position.y += -sin(player.zRotation)*10
        bulletNode.position.x += -cos(player.zRotation)*10
        
        bulletNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/500)
        bulletNode.physicsBody?.mass = 0.005
        bulletNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        bulletNode.zRotation = player.zRotation
        
        bulletNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bullet2.rawValue
        bulletNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =
        PhysicsCategory.boundary.rawValue |
        PhysicsCategory.bullet1.rawValue |
        PhysicsCategory.player1.rawValue
        
        scene.addChild(bulletNode)
        
        bulletNode.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -cos(player.zRotation)*1, dy: -sin(player.zRotation)*1))
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I need to do in order to make the timer stop calling the function after the player dies.

Comment: "what I need to do in order to make the timer stop calling the function" You would tell it to `invalidate()`.

Comment: thx that was fast